# Resetting Credentials using C# and advapi32

Tags: c#

This subject has been raised before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254980/help-with-credenumerate) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peerchan/archive/2005/11/01/credman.aspx) and although I think I followed the instructions, some of my passwords are still not being reset while the lastError is 0. Here is my code:

```
namespace ResetCredentials
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  using System.Text;

  using NDesk.Options;
  using FILETIME = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME;

  internal class Program
  {
    public enum CredPersist : uint
    {
      Session = 1,
      LocalMachine = 2,
      Enterprise = 3,
    }

    public enum CredType : uint
    {
      Generic = 1,
      DomainPassword = 2,
      DomainCertificate = 3,
      DomainVisiblePassword = 4,
      GenericCertificate = 5,
      DomainExtended = 6,
      Maximum = 7, // Maximum supported cred type
      MaximumEx = (Maximum + 1000), // Allow new applications to run on old OSes
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool CredEnumerate(
      string filter, int flag, out int count, out IntPtr pCredentials);

    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CredReadW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CredRead(
      string target, uint type, int reservedFlag, out IntPtr credentialPtr);
    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CredWriteW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CredWrite(
      [In] ref Credential userCredential, [In] UInt32 flags);

    private static void DisplayUsage(OptionSet options)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Usage: ResetCredentials.exe");
      options.WriteOptionDescriptions(Console.Out);
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string newPass = String.Empty;
      string user = String.Empty;
      OptionSet options = new OptionSet().Add("u=|user=", s 
        => user = s).Add("n=|newPass=", s => newPass = s);

      options.Parse(args);
      if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newPass))
      {
        DisplayUsage(options);
        return;
      }

      int count;
      IntPtr pCredentials;
      bool ret = CredEnumerate(null, 0, out count, out pCredentials);
      if (ret)
      {
        var credentials = new IntPtr[count];
        for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
          credentials[n] = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(
            pCredentials, n * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));

        var creds = new List<Credential>(credentials.Length);
        foreach (IntPtr ptr in credentials)
        {
          var credential = (Credential)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Credential));
          creds.Add(credential);
          if (credential.userName.Equals(
            user, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
          {
            IntPtr ptr1;
            bool b1 = CredRead(credential.targetName, credential.type, 0, out ptr1);
            int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (b1 && lastError == 0)
            {
              string currentPass = String.Empty;
              if (credential.credentialBlobSize > 0)
              {
                currentPass = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(credential.credentialBlob);
                lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
              }
              if (lastError == 0 && currentPass != null)
              {
                if (!currentPass.Equals(
                  newPass, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                  credential.credentialBlobSize                       
                    = (UInt32)Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(newPass).Length;
                  credential.credentialBlob 
                    = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni(newPass);
                  CredWrite(ref credential, 0);
                  lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                  Console.WriteLine(lastError == 0
                    ? "Token: {0} password changed"
                    : "Could not reset password for {0}",
                      credential.targetName);
                }
              }
              else
                Console.WriteLine(
                  "Could not retrieve password for {0}", credential.targetName);
            }
            else
              Trace.WriteLine("Error: " + lastError);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct Credential
    {
      public readonly UInt32 flags;
      public readonly UInt32 type;
      public readonly string targetName;
      public readonly string comment;
      public readonly FILETIME lastWritten;
      public UInt32 credentialBlobSize;
      public IntPtr credentialBlob;
      public readonly UInt32 persist;
      public readonly UInt32 attributeCount;
      public readonly IntPtr credAttribute;
      public readonly string targetAlias;
      public readonly string userName;
    }
  }
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Comment on quality of question: please inline what your question actually is in addition to linking to other questions. Also consider making sample significantly smaller. Also be careful to post code that you think is part of your product/company property (based on lines in DisplayUsage) as license on code on SO may not be compatible with policy your code needs to comply with.

Comment: Thanks Alexei. I own the company and I intend to release this utility as free anyhow. The code could be smaller. I wanted reviewers to have the whole picture. Anyhow, the problem here is that some password will get refreshed, while other will not. No rhyme nor reason, but there are no errors. It simply succeeds, but if you ran it again and again, the same credentials will be listed all over again.

Comment: Did you ever got it to work?

Comment: Nope. I did not. But I've managed to lock my AD account a few times in the process ... :-)